# How to use Validation for a php register page?

Tags: php

```
<?php
session_start();
$username = "";
$email = "";


$db = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "authentication");

if (isset($_POST['register_btn'])) {
    $username = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['username']);
    $email = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['email']);
    $password = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['password']);
    $password2 = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['password2']);



    $user_check_query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='$username' OR email='$email' LIMIT 1";
    $result = mysqli_query($db, $user_check_query);
    $user = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);

    if ($user) {
        if ($user['username'] === $username) {
            header("Refresh:0");
            echo "usrname exists";
        }

        if ($user['email'] === $email) {
            header("Refresh:0");
            echo "error";
        }
    }


    if ($password == $password2) {

        $password = md5($password); 
        $sql = "INSERT INTO users
                    (username, email, password, name, street, 
                    postcode, age , center) 
                VALUES('$username', '$email', '$password', '$name', '$street', 
                        '$postcode', '$age', '$center')";
        mysqli_query($db, $sql); 
        $_SESSION['message'] = "Account registered";
        $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
        header("location: login.php"); 
    }else{
        $_ERROR= "Something went wrong :/";
    }
}
```

As shown above is some PHP code, the purpose here is to register a user then redirect them to the login page, however after multiple attempts of trying to use validation to see if an email or username already exists, after clicking the register button it still just records the registered details into the database names authentication (Users). I have put 'header ("Refresh") to test if it even reads through the if statement, It does not seem to.
I know md5 is insecure, and I will replace it.

Any advice on what I may have done wrong.
I have used snippets of code from [here](https://codewithawa.com/posts/complete-user-registration-system-using-php-and-mysql-database) however I have attempted a few other solutions with no luck.

Comment: what is the output of `var_dump($user);`?

Comment: Your script is wide open to [SQL Injection Attack](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)
Even [if you are escaping inputs, its not safe!](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187/sql-injection-that-gets-around-mysql-real-escape-string)
Use [prepared parameterized statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) in either the `MYSQLI_` or `PDO` API's

Comment: And you should AVOID like the PLAGUE any tutorials that use `mysqli_real_escape_string()` as that only demonstrates that the rest of the tutorial is likely to be very low quality

Comment: Your problem is that when you find an error situation you dont stop the code executing. So it just continues on to the INSERT stage.

Comment: Some sensible code indentation (like I changed it to) would help you see these sort of issues a lot easier

Comment: learn to use return;  `header("Refresh:0");
            echo "error";
return;`

Comment: I highly appreciate the feedback, and the correct indentation, the comment by hanshenrik solved the issue, and i understand my program might be less secure than a open window but this program is only for personal experimental purposes.